# Is there any alternative to send push notifications without the need of using Google services?

Tags: android, push-notification

I use Firebase to send push notifications to my app´s users (Created with Android Studio), but I am searching for an alternative that does not require to use Google services. Maybe a way to use a socket or I don´t know.

Does anyone know another way?

I found several options besides Firebase but they still use Google services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO make push messaging work, you need a process on the client (the Android device) with an open socket connection to somewhere and (important part) this process can never be killed.  Or if it is, it's restarted immediately.  For FCM, this is done by a process in the Android OS, which then sends any incoming messages to the proper app.

THe difficulty here is that an Android app can't promise that it will always be running.  It can be killed by the OS at any moment.  If you're the OEM, you can add a Linux level process that does the same thing and it will work for your devices.  But if you're putting an app in the play store, that won't work.  So you'll have to decide what level of reliability you're willing to accept.  Because anytime the OS kills your app, you will stop receiving push messages.  There are definitely things you can do, but they will be less reliable than FCM (which already isn't 100% reliable).

Comment: I see, so there´s really no point in sending push notifications if the user will only see the messages in the notifications panel once they restart the app, right?

Comment: Yeah, at that point you may as well poll.  If you expect the user to keep the app open for an extended time it could still make sense, as you could avoid polling for new messages and just react to the pushes.  But you really need that permanent process for reliability.  My real suggestion would be to just use FCM, there's really not a good alternative to it.

Comment: Yeah, I have come to that conclusion now.  Stick to FCM or maybe try with Pushy to see if paying for it is worth it